# Is there an equivalent to "antisémites" for muslims?

Tags: vocabulaire

The other day, I was talking with someone on a chat. I wanted to talk about "people who hate muslims", which made me wonder whether or not there was an equivalent of "antisémites", which means "people who hate jews".

Is there a word to qualify hatred toward muslims?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the word " islamophobe "